# Enforcing type check only on object's properties, derive keys as const

Tags: typescript

I often find myself confused when defining **constants with predefined keys** in typescript.
Let's go through an example:

```
// let's say I have the following object
const MY_LIB = {
    id_1: {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'},
    id_2: {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}
} as const

// later, I might want to create a type based on it, like so:
type LibIds = keyof typeof MY_LIB // 'id_1' | 'id_2'
```

That's all good so far.

HOWEVER, especially in case of very large objects, with lots of keys and more complex properties (i.e. with other nested objects), I might want to enforce a type check on the library object itself, like so:

```
// let's say I have the following object
const MY_LIB: Record<string, {foo: string, bar: string}> = {
    id_1: {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'},
    id_2: {foo: 'foo', bar: 123} // error caught! - bar should be a string
} as const

// however, now my type doesn't work anymore, and it's of a generic value "string"
type LibIds = keyof typeof MY_LIB // string
```

My desired behavior would be something like this:

```
type ReadonlyLibrary<Libtype> = // implementation here

const MY_LIB: ReadonlyLibrary<{foo: stringl bar: string}> = {
    id_1: {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'},
    id_2: {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}
}
// MY_LIB is of type: {[key: 'id_1' | 'id_2']: {foo: stringl bar: string}}

// so now this work as well as I need it
type LibKeys = keyof typeof MY_LIB // 'id1' | 'id_2'
```

How do you usually go about this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `satisfies` operator:

```ts
const MY_LIB = {
    id_1: {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'},
    id_2: {foo: 'foo', bar: 123} // error caught! - bar should be a string
} as const satisfies Record<string, {foo: string, bar: string}>;


type LibIds = keyof typeof MY_LIB // "id_1" | "id_2"
```

See [The satisfies Operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator)

Before satisfies operator was introduced in TS 4.9, the way to approach it was a constrained identity fuction:

```ts
function createMyLib <T extends Record<string, {foo: string, bar: string}>>(def: T): T {
  return def;
}
export const MY_LIB = createMyLib({
  id_1: {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'},
  id_2: {foo: 'foo', bar: '123'} 
} as const);

type LibIds = keyof typeof MY_LIB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `satisfies` operator, which [came with typescript 4.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html). It checks if the type fits the given object, but infers the type from the object itself.

```
const MY_LIB = {
  id_1: { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' },
  id_2: { foo: 'foo', bar: '123' },
} satisfies Record<string, { foo: string; bar: string }>;

type LibIds = keyof typeof MY_LIB; // "id_1" | "id_2"
```